# Obtaining a Taiwanese visa in Hong Kong

Tags: visas, hong-kong, taiwan

Is there a way to obtain a Taiwanese visa while visiting Hong Kong? If so, what is the best way of doing this? Are there any agencies I should contact, or should I go directly to some Taiwan consulate in HK directly? Does anyone has any experience with this?

Also, where can I find a list of required documents needed to obtain a visa?

Comment: What is your nationality and what type of visa do you want to apply for? Following the links from here https://www.roc-taiwan.org/sa_en/post/111.html it appears you apply online and via the local Taipei Economic & Cultural Centre in HK

Comment: @Traveller My nationality is Russian Federation, and the visa type is a tourist visa (or whatever it is called). I wasn't able to find anything about applying in HK following your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Taiwan is considered to be part of China, and Taiwan considers the Mainland a part of its territory too, there's no consulate of Taiwan in HK. They do have a Taipei Economic and Cultural Office (Hong Kong), in
Lippo Centre, 89 Queensway, Tower 1, room 1106. Phone: 2525.8316. They're the ones you want to talk to.

Alternatively, any big travel agency (CTS, Travel Expert, etc) should be able to handle this for you.